# Prevent unauthroized calls to API

Tags: php, mysql, api, security, paypal

I am working on an API that can be used between my server and my iOS app. I have an SQL database that contains an Accounts table which includes a column called BALANCE.

People can make a real money deposit to my website through PayPal or I will be allowing them to send money orders. The problem is, when the PayPal SDK checks to make sure it was a legitimate deposit, then it credits that users account balance. When I receive the money order, I credit their balance via my website.

Each time the balance is credited, a call to my API happens. The thing is, I can do this over and over without actually getting PayPal deposits or money order deposits.

See, the users will transfer balances between each others accounts. So I don't need any help with making sure deposits were legit, I got that already. Right now a simple API call will transfer one balance amount over to another account without proof that the call was for a legitimate reason. I don't want to be able to have people somehow tap into the API and credit their own balance somehow. It needs to be where people can't just alter it.

So what can I put in place so that people cannot just tap into my API and credit their balance without actually sending money? Since this is real money, I am putting a lot of time into security.

Answer (score 0):

You could authenticate with [OAuth](http://oauth.net/2/), which is what the majority of web service API's are using these days.

This [tutorial](http://www.devx.com/webdev/create-your-own-rest-api-using-oauth-authentication.html) may be of interest to you.

Comment: I know how to use PayPal IPN, but the issue isn't that. The application is going to be transferring balances between users. I want to secure the API in a way so it knows that this balance transfer is legit.

Comment: Hmmm, well, the answer is simply to authenticate with OAuth, which protects the web service, which is what the question was.  The procedure for that is outlined in the links I provided.

Comment: So by using OAuth a user can't go to the URL bar and enter in the credit balance command without certain one-time tokens generated at that time?

Comment: Right. Without a valid token they won't have permissions to do anything with the service.  You could also just setup a username and password that is required for the service to run correctly.  That might be easier if you're the only one using it.

Comment: Cool. I looked at OAuth last week but must've misunderstood how it works. Thanks for clearing that up for me!